# Get Command.ignore_extra = False by default on Discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am building a Discord bot and I want to add an error handler that tells the user they used too many arguments.

To do that, I need to change the `Command.ignore_extra` property of each command to `False`, which is `True` by default.

Is there a way to change the default value of this attribute without having to change it in every single command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this code after cogs loading:

```py
for command in client.commands:
    command.ignore_extra = False
```

This code will set `ignore_extra` attribute to False for all registered commands.